How do I specify a date property using Zod in Firebase Genkit?
I am trying to create an Tool for one of my Genkit functions that will be used for finding appointment times using an external API. I defined my Schema like this:
export const SearchCriteria = z.object({
  zip: z.string(),
  date: z.string().datetime({ offset: false }),
  timeOfDay: z.enum(["morning", "afternoon", "evening"]).optional(),
});

And the tool function looks like this:
const searchAppointments = defineTool(
  {
    name: "searchAppointments",
    description: "Use this to search for appointments in a given zip code.",
    inputSchema: SearchCriteria,
    outputSchema: AppointmentResults,
  },
  async (search) => {

    const response = await fetch(
      `{my_endpoint}?zip=${search.zip}&startDate=${search.date}`
    );

    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
  }
);

When I try to use the function, I get this error:

name: 'Error',
message: 'unknown format "date" ignored in schema at path "#/properties/date"',

Based on this file, it appears that Genkit only supports string and number data types.
/node_modules/@genkit-ai/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/vocabularies/format/format.js:63:23
Aside from casting Dates to Strings and vice versa, is there a way to use the Date type in Genkit

Dates might not have been tested well. There are nontrivial interactions between 3 different libraries happening there: schema defined by Zod, converted to JSON schema with zod-to-json-schema and validated by ajv. Will take a look....

It appears that Genkit does not install format validators for dates, etc: https://ajv.js.org/packages/ajv-formats.html
I filed an issue: https://github.com/firebase/genkit/issues/206
As a workaround for now, add a description for the date format you want for the field and LLMs seem to understand it well:
export const SearchCriteria = z.object({
  zip: z.string(),
  date: z.string().describe("Date in ISO 8601 format"),
  timeOfDay: z.enum(["morning", "afternoon", "evening"]).optional(),
});

